# How to rewrite this url in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I have multiple urls in this manner.

```
http://domain.com/something/static/variable/
```

But now I want to redirect the url above to

```
http://domain.com/anything/static/variable/
```

I tried

```
location /something{
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com/anything$request_uri? permanent;
    }
```

But that redirects to

```
http://domain.com/anything/something/static/variable/
```

How to fix this rewrite rule?

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
location ~ ^/something/(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com/anything/$1? permanent;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry it was redirecting me /anything without variables. Can you please edit your answer and remove the domain name from it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rewrite ^/something/(.+)$ http://domain.com/anything/$1 permanent;`
I used this and it's working perfectly.